# How to print double quotation using awk?

Tags: bash, text, awk, append

I have to append to a specific line of a file the following text containing double quotations:

```
execfile(r"/'${path}'/'Template_${step_x}_${step_y}'/prova.py")
```

I tried to use the following commmand:

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==20{print"execfile(r"/'${path}'/'Template_${step_x}_${step_y}'/prova.py")"}1' ${file}
```

But I get a syntax error. I tried to use `\47` or `"\""` for the double quotations but they don't seem to work.

Comment: If you include the actual syntax error message in your question that'd be far more useful in helping debug it than just saying you `get a syntax error`.

Answer (score 1):

You may print quoting awk like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "execfile(r\"/\047${path}\047/\047Template_${step_x}_${step_y}\047/prova.py\")"}'
```

```
execfile(r"/'${path}'/'Template_${step_x}_${step_y}'/prova.py")
```

So always escape a double quote and use `\047` to print a single quote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still get syntax error even with your code..

Comment: @GianmarcoBroilo again - don;t just tell us you got a syntax error, tell us what the error message is so we can help you debug it.